# How to select from only one array out of other arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays

```
$arr_1 = array('a','b','c');
$arr_2 = array('d','e','f');
$arr_3 = array('g','h','i');
```

Assuming these 3 arrays are for values from 3 select menus in a form. I want to implement the following.

If the form is submitted, if an element in `$arr_1` is selected and any element is selected again from either `$arr_2` or `$arr_3` it will alert error that you can only select from either `$arr_1` or `$arr_2` or `$arr_3` and not a mix of elements from the 3 arrays.

Comment: what u have tried so far? show me your logic and code

Answer (score 2):

```
$valid = array('a', 'b');
$invalid = array('a', 'd');

$arrays = array(
    '1' => array('a', 'b', 'c'),
    '2' => array('d', 'e', 'f'),
    '3' => array('g', 'h', 'i'),
);

foreach ($valid as $input) {
    $inArray = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $key => $array)
        if (in_array($input, $array))
            $inArray[] = $key;
}

foreach ($invalid as $input) {
    $numberOfArrays = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $key => $array)
        if (in_array($input, $array))
            $inArray[] = $key;
}
```

You can proof with the length of `$inArray` i.e.

```
if (length($inArray) === 1) { 
    echo 'Valid'; 
} else { 
    echo 'Invalid'; 
}
```

**Edit:**

And to proof if all values are from one array:

```
if ((length($inArray) === 1) and (length($valid) === length($arrays['1']))) {
    echo 'Valid';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid';
}
```

Comment: With regards your $valid and $invalid; only valid combination is either only elements from $arr_1 is selected or $arr_2 or $arr_3 and not any element from either $arr_1 and $arr_2 and $arr_3.

Comment: So you want to check if all values ("a, b, c" or "d, e, f") are selected not only one?

Comment: Yes. Just as my question posited above.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like

```
if($arr_1 && $arr_2 && $arr_3){

    alert("error ");

} else if ($arr_1 && $arr_2){

    alert("error");
} else {

   alert("good to go");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check how many form values corresponding to the select menus are different from their default ones (which should not be in these arrays):

```
<?php
$form_select = array('select1' => 'none','select2' => 'none','select3' => 'none');
if (count(array_intersect_assoc($_REQUEST, $form_select)) < count($form_select) - 1)
    display_error();
else
    process_form($_REQUEST);
```

where `$form_select` contains the default values for select menus which cannot be used together.

The coresponding html would look like:

```
 <form>
  <select name='select1'>
    <option value ='none' selected>none</option>
    <?php array_walk($arr_1, function ($v) { echo '<option value="'.$v.'">'.$v.'</option>'; }); ?>
  </select>
  <!-- etc. -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already got all HTML issues sorted out. I only need to check one last PHP error then process form. 

Just like I explain above, I have 3 Select menu that doesn't need all 3 fields selected at a time. Once you select from Select menu A then needless selecting from either Select menu B or C. I want to print an error if values from Select A and or Select B or C is selected same time.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I assumed I had to write the whole thing since you didn't give indication of the html or php you already have. My bad.

Comment: I'm trying out a work around based on your code. I'll alert you in a giffy if it worked me to my solution. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Assuming I have text boxes inclusive instead of just select menu, how do I implement this solution?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Do you have textboxes or select menus?

Comment: assuming you _also_ have textboxes inclusive, the solution would have to be extended to support either regexps or custom validation functions.